# Using CXF's wsdl2java, is there an easier way to generate package names from xml namespaces without version numbers?

Tags: java, namespaces, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm using Apache CXF's wsdl2java utility to create some JAXB objects and some web service code.  The schema in my WSDL has a lot of namespaces with version numbers on the end.  For example:

```
http://example.org/sample/namespace/1.0
```

When CXF generates my JAXB objects the packages wind up with package names like this:

```
org.example.sample.namespace.1_0
```

Since this is a large schema with many different namespaces I have to spend quite a bit of time either re-factoring code, or using the -p option to manually map the namespaces to package names.  Both processes are very time consuming.

So, I'm wondering if anyone knows if there is an easier route.  Or am I being too fussy and I should just accept the package names as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bunch of `-p` flags is probably the quickest way to map namespaces to package names.  In my research I've also found that you can achieve this by using the `-b` option to pass in a JAXB binding file (I'm a little new to JAXB).  This is also a good solution but requires a little more effort than using a bunch of `-p` flags.  Also, the JAXB binding file is probably better in the long run, so you can repeat the process if necessary.